# How to use data augmentation in the context of model evaluation in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to use data augmentation for training a model for a classification task.
But I'm not sure about how to use data augmentation in a fair and meaningful way in the evaluation of a machine learning model.
I have considered at least three different options for doing this and I would like to know which one is the best.

Firt of all, let us suppose that we have a labeled dataset D.

Option 1:

```
-We can use a data augmentation approach over D, for generating a novel set of synthetic data S.
-We can create a new dataset D2, which combines D and S.
-With D2, we can use a 10-fold cross-validation approach, where:
    -We divide D2 into 10 random subsets (folds).
    -We use each fold as test data and the remaining 9 folds as training data.
    -This is repeated for each fold.
    -We obtain the average performance (on the 10 folds) for evaluating the model.
```

Option 2:

```
-We can use a data augmentation approach over D, for generating a novel set of synthetic data S.
-With D, we can use a 10-fold cross-validation approach, where:
    -We divide D into 10 random subsets (folds).
    -We use each fold as test.
    -We create a set T including the remaining 9 folds.
    -We create a new set T2 that combines T and S
    -We use T2 as the training data.
   -This is repeated for each fold.
   -We obtain the average performance (on the 10 folds) for evaluating the model.
```

Option 3:

```
-From D, we can use a 10-fold cross-validation approach, where:
       -We divide D into 10 random subsets (folds).
       -We use each fold as test.
       -We create a set T including the remaining 9 folds.
       -We use a data augmentation approach over T for generating a set S of synthetic samples.
       -We create a set T2 that combines T and S.
       -We use T2 as the training data.
       -This is repeated for each fold.
       -We obtain the average performance for evaluating the model.
```

What is the best option and why?

Answer (score 2):

Option 3.

Options 1 and 2 have an information bleed-through issue between your train/validation data. Because you are creating S BEFORE splitting into folds, you will have synthetic data that was created from observations in your validation fold. By having data that is in some way only a slight permutation of your validation data, you haven't properly separated your validation/train data.

Option 3 is the only one that does not have the bleed-through issue because S is only created based on T.